# In Cpanel limit folder name characters

Tags: php, cpanel

I have thousands of folders in my cpanel. I want to make sure name of the folder does not exist 50 characters. So if there is folder: 
teaching-institue-cleveland-ohio-learn-at-your-pace-great

i want it to show like this: 
teaching-institue-cleveland-ohio-learn-at-your-pac

Is there an easy way to do this in cpanel? I am using godaddy server.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember there was nothing about folder limits in the cPanel documentation or cPanel certification. This sounds like something that may need to be done at the OS level, The problem with this is that there may be folders over 50 characters in length and changing the core OS settings can cause issues.

By default linux has a maximum filename length of 255 characters for most filesystems (including EXT4), and a maximum path of 4096 characters. If you have root access and are still wanting to proceede I would recommend looking at https://serverfault.com/questions/9546/filename-length-limits-on-linux for more information.